# How to position image to be directly vertically centered between two elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the Texas icon directly centered between the span and h1 element.

Here is the [Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tIfX.png)

I tried googling but I think I might be phrasing what I need poorly. Is it that I have to adjust the padding and margin in css? I just want to move the icon down the y-axis.

Thank you

```
 <header id="top" class="main-header">
      <span class="title">Keep it Weird in</span>
   <div>
    <img class="texas-icon" src="https://image.ibb.co/cGRVFG/texasicon_1.png" alt="texasicon_1" border="0"></a>
      </div>
      <h1>Austin</h1>



    .main-header {
  padding-top: 170px;
  height: 850px;
  background: linear-gradient(lightblue, transparent 90%),
              linear-gradient(0deg, #fff, transparent),
              #ffa949 url('https://media.giphy.com/media/3ohs7I9ho0H4dfeP7y/giphy.gif') no-repeat center;

  background-size: cover;



}

.title {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.625rem; /* 26px/16px */
  letter-spacing: .065em;
  font-weight: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
h1 {  
  font-size: 12.5rem; /* 90px/16px  */
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin: 12px 0px 0px;
     }
```

Comment: You're looking for `vertical centering`.  You could use either margin-top or padding-top.  However, to answer this question properly, we need to see the relevant CSS.  Please add it to the question.

Comment: You can always make use of flexbox as well by just adding these 3 lines to your header class {display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content: space-between;}.

Answer (score 1):

I think `text-align:center` is enough in your case, then simply play with margin of elements to create the spaces :

```css
header {
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  max-height: 380px;
  padding: 50px 25px 0px;
}

.title {
  margin: 5px 0;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

h1 {
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-size: 5rem;
  line-height: 1.1;
}
```

```html
<header id="top" class="main-header">
  <span class="title">Keep it Weird in</span>
  <div>
    <a href=""><img class="texas-icon" src="https://image.ibb.co/cGRVFG/texasicon_1.png" alt="texasicon_1" border="0"></a>
  </div>
  <h1>Austin</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: @NataliePickrom you welcome, i also advice to keep searching as you will find a lot of way to do this (flex, column, table, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the support. Unfortunately, none of the solutions worked but I decided just to change the line height of the h1 element and was able to get the result I wanted. I learned so many new things from the responses to my question. Again, thank you.
[Updated Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zf1Pc.png)